# Dynamic Text View MaxLength

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a value by the user in a `TextView`. I then need to use this value in a second Activity to set the `maxLength` of a `TextView` field to that value.

The issue I am having in with the `Intent`. I cannot parse the `Integer` to the second activity successfully. I have tried multiple resources and it still does not work. Can anyone help?

The code for the **first Activity** is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText bcLength = findViewById(R.id.bcLength);
    Button next = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
            String length = bcLength.getText().toString();
            Integer.parseInt(length);

            myIntent.putExtra(length, Integer.parseInt(length.toString()));

            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });
```

The **second Activity** is:

```
 Intent myIntent = getIntent();


    int length = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(length);

    /* String length =  myIntent.getIntExtra(); */

    InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(Integer.parseInt(length));
    length.setFilters(filterArray);
```

The issue is I am not understanding if I need to convert the string value entered to an Int and then call up the Int in my **getIntExtra()** method or should I call it as a String?

This then causes issues with my **setFilters** section.

Thank you for taking the time to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in first activity

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
            String length = bcLength.getText().toString().length();


            myIntent.putExtra("length",length)
```

Now in second activity use this code`

```
String strValue =getIntent().getExtras().getString("length");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This sort of works. I edited it it like this: String length = bcLength.getText().toString();
                length.length();

Comment: and if my solution helps you to find your problem and seems useful then please mark this as an accepted answer and give an upvote if possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the value to another activity, your code in sending activity will remain same as below.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("variableName", intValue);    //you can use int or string here
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Depending on what type of value you pass, if you passed int and want to retrieve it you need to use **getIntExtra()**

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("variableName", 0);
```

And if you want to get the string value that you passed in source activity you need to use **getExtras().getString()**

```
Intent mIntent= getIntent();
String strValue = mIntent.getExtras().getString("variableName");
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have managed to figure it out using Pankaj Kumar 's code (see below) .

Answer (score 0):

If You're trying to get the length of the string in the textview, I don't see the code for that in your first activity.

`Integer.parseInt(length);`  turns a string to its equivalence value as an integer. Using it on a string which can't be turned to an int would result in a runtime exception

What you should do is to call `length.toString();` which gives you the length of that string.

Then you can pass that to your second activity

Also, You put an extra into your intent by
`myIntent.putExtra("referenceName", ValueToBePassed);` and get it by
 `int strValue = mIntent.getExtras().getString("referenceName");`
The value passed can be of any type
So passing a string lets you get an int type